# Water reflection malfunctions in landscape scene

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows, reflection

I just did a first cycles render of my first landscape scene (see attached). Upon first inspection I noticed a part of the reflection of the cherry blossom tree was too clear compared to the rest of it. I tried messing around with lighting and turning off parts of the model and noticed it might be due to the direct shadow of the trees onto the water. Any advise on how this might be resolved?
[image]

Comment: Hmm, I've never had that issue before. It could be so many different things. It's possible that it's an issue in your shader if you are controlling the roughness somehow. Or it could be an issue with the light passes somehow, and the shadow is actually what's causing the strange reflection. Or maybe you actually have another copy of the tree still in that spot, but it's hidden (in the viewport, but not in the render). Maybe it's on another layer that's being rendered. Maybe it's the ground that's over the water that's a reflective material. There are way too many possibilities to know.

Comment: Please try to add your screenshot directly within your post using the Image icon in the Edit tools. This way the link won't expire or disappear. Can you change it?

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Sorry for that, added the picture, had to reduce quality for 2MB limit, but it is still visible.

Comment: save the file with a new name, remove or simplify something (remove the islands for example), do again the render, is the problem still there?, remove or simplify something (remove the grass), is the problem still there?, remove or simplify something (remove nodes from the water).... this is the process I suggest you to follow.